# TFS, changing states of different work items

Tags: tfs, workflow

I have been searching for a possible solution for my problem. Is it possible to change the status of a work item within TFS and then have that change reflect a different change upon a different work item? Example:

I link a task to a requirement such that requirement is parent and task is a child. If I mark the task as status = "closed", I would like for my requirement status = "closed", reason = "completed"

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:
http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/